# Unable to delete a row completely from GridBagSizer in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to dynamically delete a set of buttons in a row in a GridBagSizer then reuse the cell space to generate a new set of buttons but when I try to Add the new buttons to the newly deleted row it says that I am unable to as there is an item already in that position.

```
    def delete_tool(self, event, specific_option=None):

        for i in range(0 , 7):
            item = self.activetoolsizer.FindItemAtPosition((specific_option, i)) 
            item.Show(False)
            self.activetoolsizer.Layout()
        self.activetoolcount -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `item.Show(False)` which merely hides the item, you need to use `item.Destroy()` which removes it.
Later you can `self.activetoolsizer.Add(......)` at that position and remember to use `self.activetoolsizer.Layout()`

Silly example (keep clicking button 1 and button 2 will be removed and then replaced):

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self,-1, "Button 1")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self,-1, "Button 2")
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(2, 2)
        self.sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self,-1, "Label 1"), (0, 0), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button1, (0, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button2, (1, 0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add (wx.StaticText(self,-1, "Label 2"), (1, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button_click, self.button1)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.button_index = 3

    def button_click(self, event):
        item = self.sizer.FindItemAtPosition((1, 0))
        if (item != None):
            self.button2.Destroy()
        else:
            self.button2 = wx.Button(self,-1, "Button "+str(self.button_index))
            self.sizer.Add(self.button2, (1, 0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
            self.sizer.Layout()
            self.button_index +=1

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "Replace item in Gridbagsizer")
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```